# List of Strings unable create

Tags: java

I am trying to understand how to create array lists in Java, for some reason I am getting an error saying to change the type of myList to ArrayList even though I saw this example from a different post on stack overflow and it seemed to work.

What I am trying to do is simply create a List, add three strings to it and iterate through it and print it out.

On a side note, is it possible to add integers, strings, and objects all to the same list?

I'd appreciate any guidance in this regard.

```
    List myList = new ArrayList(); 


            myList.add("hello");
            myList.add("World");
            myList.add("!");

//print contents
System.out.println(myList);
```

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList to List, however, I was wondering why the code above would work for some people but not for me...

Comment: Please see my comment below about importing the right List.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My guess is that you've imported `java.util.ArrayList`, but not `java.util.List`. The code you've posted works if you import both:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        List myList = new ArrayList(); 

        myList.add("hello");
        myList.add("World");
        myList.add("!");

        //print contents
        System.out.println(myList);
    }
}
```

Having said that, I'd strongly urge you to use generics:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 1):

> On a side note, is it possible to add integers, strings, and objects all to the same list?

Though you can add any type of `Object` to a `List`, it is not recommended. If you are using JDK 1.5 or higher, you should avoid creating unsafe collections and use `Generics`.

> List myList = new ArrayList();

Regarding this, check if you have the right List. It should be `java.util.List` and not `java.awt.List` (which often comes up above in Eclipse auto-suggest feature for me!)

Comment: I didn't ask about Generics, but ok. Also, I am using the right List.

Comment: Then check if you are using the right ArrayList, i.e. `java.util.ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use String type in your list(List) rather than generic(List).

```
        List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        myList.add("hello");
        myList.add("World");
        myList.add("!");
        for(String str : myList){
            System.out.println(str);
        }
```